# Ruby on Rails Facebook Graph API OAuth error #506 Duplicate status message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-oauth, rescue

I have a Rails application that is posting to Facebook. I put a rescue to prevent the error of posting the same message twice. I would like to have my app just notify the user and move on, but I cannot seem to rescue this error.

This is my code:

```
begin
  current_user.facebook.feed!(:message => 'THIS IS A TEST PLEASE IGNORE::Hello, Facebook!')
rescue FbGraph::Unauthorized
  flash[:alert] = "Already Posted"
end
redirect_to show(@track)
```

The error I get with this code is:

> OAuthException :: (#506) Duplicate status message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are rescuing from `FbGraph::Unauthorized` when you're getting an `OAuthException` error?

```
begin
  current_user.facebook.feed!(:message => 'THIS IS A TEST PLEASE IGNORE::Hello, Facebook!')
rescue OAuthException
  flash[:alert] = "Already Posted"
end
redirect_to show(@track)
```

Comment: I could not get it to work with OAuthException or Exception::OAuthException.  They said unknown exception, but I just rescued all exceptions instead

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
begin
  current_user.facebook.feed!(:message => 'THIS IS A TEST PLEASE IGNORE::Hello, Facebook!')
rescue => e
  if(e.fb_error_type == "OAuthException" 
   flash[:alert] = "Already Posted"
  end
end
```